# Redshift stored procedure dependency handling

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

We have 10 stored procedures stored in **redshift** database  - Each procedure has dependency on each other .

Example:

1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 4 <- 5 <- 6 <- 7 <- 8 <- 9 <- 10

Assume if 5th procedure fails , if we restart the process it has to start from 5th not from the 1st procedure .

without using **AWS step functions** - can we handle this dependency ?

currently we are running it manually through **event bridge** [ one after other ] .

Is there any other approach .

Comment: seems like a data processing pipeline. why not use specialized tools like Airflow?

Comment: no thrid party softwares .. only we have to use aws  services - we dont want to use step functions